# Youtube API single-user scenario with OAuth (uploading videos)

Tags: oauth, youtube-api, access-token, single-user

This question has been already asked, but never answered.

I want to write some php scripts that would upload video to my own YouTube account. I have already registered the application and have the developer key, the customer key and the customer secret.

I don't need to allow any user to upload video to their own accounts, so I don't need to go through the full OAuth process; especially I don't need to redirect anybody anywhere: I only need my scripts to authenticate on MY behalf (not on anybody else's behalf).

I know I can use ClientLogin authentication, but I've read on the YouTube API documentation site that it is "not recommended for new development" and I'm afraid this means that support for it will be discontinued in a near future. So I'd prefer to use OAuth.

The Twitter API, which also uses OAuth, provides a simple way to authenticate with the application's owner's own account, in a single step, using an access token that you can find on your application's administration page.
How can I obtain a similar token for my Youtube application?

Thanks
m.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try OAuth 2.0 for installed application: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#OAuth2_Installed_Applications_Flow

First, register the API to get a client_id.

Then, log into your google account, type the following URL, change the client_id with yours. redirect_uri should be set to "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&response_type=code&access_type=offline

Then you authorize your own application and get an authorization code.

Then open a terminal and type (change your code, client_id, and client_secret):

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -d "code=4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf&client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSe&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code"
```

You will get response like:

`{
  "access_token" : "ya29.AHES6ZTtm7SuokEB-RGtbBty9IIlNiP9-eNMMQKtXdMP3sfjL1Fc",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : "1/HKSmLFXzqP0leUihZp2xUt3-5wkU7Gmu2Os_eBnzw74"
}`

Remember the refresh_token, and every time you run your application, you need to get a new access_token with the refresh_token.

Comment: It worked like a charm except it is worth to mention that 1) code can be used just once; 2) code is valid only for 10 mins (so hurry); 3) I had to set extra parameter **approval_prompt** as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth)`If you need long-lived access to the YouTube API in a web application, you can retrieve one by setting the access_type parameter to offline and the approval_prompt parameter to force in the initial authorization request or your client configuration.`

Comment: Hey @DrXCheng thanks for the help as i can get access token for the other type app with the help of your code, but I can't get accessToken and refresh token for the web server app and ios app so can you please help me. if I go through ios app then i don't have client secret so how can i get access token and refresh token ?