# Youtube V3 Playlists.List - Post to API without user browser login

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am able to upload a video via the youtube v3 api and authorisation works fine using the YoutubeUpload scope. I am now trying to list all my playlists but i am getting **Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.** I have tried using the YoutubeReadonly, Youtube & YoutubeForceSsl scopes, also tried combinations of them all and it never seems to authenticate. It seems I do not have access to do anything with playlists, create, list or add a video. Strange thing is this code worked about 5 months ago but my dev account got disabled for inactivity, so i created a new one.

I'm happy to post the code here if needed but I believe this may be to do with the way I have set up the OAuth credentials / project. The steps i took to create are below.

Google Developers Console (console.developers.google.com)
    - Create project
    - Configure consent screen
    - Create OAuth credentials (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)
        - Application type: Other
    - Enable APIs and services (YouTube Data API v3)
        - Enable
    - APIs & Services
        - OAuth consent screen
            - Tick youtube scopes (YouTube, YouTubeForceSSL, ReadOnly, Upload)

Any help would be much appreciated and if i can provide any further information please let me know.

**EDIT:**
I tried creating another account, added secrets, ran it and my code seemed to work fine. So I went back to the account I was having issues with and it came up in the browser asking for google sign in, this time it worked fine. So I guess my next questions is, can you authorise the application / OAuth creds without having to open a web browser? I will have multiple YouTube accounts to manage so would be great to be able to deal with this before making any requests.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this post has been viewed a few times so i thought i'd mention that my solution was answered here

[Auto Upload of Videos to my account, using youtube Data API V3 without user consent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633200/auto-upload-of-videos-to-my-account-using-youtube-data-api-v3-without-user-cons)

Hope this helps other in future!