# Get Refresh Token in Google OAuth2.0 .NET

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-oauth-.net-client

I have problem using `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` to authenticate, and looking at some other questions here I went for `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow`. The thing is to use this method I need to get the refresh token.

I have manage to do that following the steps given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850287/youtube-api-single-user-scenario-with-oauth-uploading-videos/8876027#8876027), but I haven't find a way of replicating this steps from inside the code in c#.

Is there some way of getting a refresh token and access token using the Google Api?

This is where I need to use it:

```
ClientSecrets clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets();
clientSecrets.ClientId = id;
clientSecrets.ClientSecret = secret;
String scope = StorageService.Scope.CloudPlatform;

var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = "???" };
var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = clientSecrets
                }),
                "user",
                token);
storageService = new StorageService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                ApplicationName = app,
            });
```

Comment: have you seen [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token) I think this is relative to what you are seeking.

Comment: that is what i'm doing from command line to get the token, but I don't know what I need to do to get the same result using [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/oauth2/v2)

Comment: @moondaisy any solution for this?