# How to register with Google to be able to upload videos to YouTube from your desktop using C#

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am writing an application that uploads videos to youtube from a desktop. It will be used only by me, so there is no issue with authentication or giving any access rights).

I found this post that shows me how to upload using C# [How to upload Video to youtube using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593609/how-to-upload-video-to-youtube-using-google-apis-youtube-v3-and-c)

But this requires ClientId, Client Secret, and refresh token. I can get a refresh token by signing in to Google as explained here:

[Youtube API single-user scenario with OAuth (uploading videos)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850287/youtube-api-single-user-scenario-with-oauth-uploading-videos/8876027#8876027)

But how can I get the two other values?
As it is for my own use, is there any more straightforward way to do this without the need to have a client ID and Client Secret?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your application on [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard). And create desk top credentials. Or installed / native app credentials [How to create Google Oauth2 installed application credentials.json.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwqJcyLQSSQ)

Once you do that the google .net client library will handle authorization for you.